# What is a healthy interval for triggering AlarmManager for running a background service?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

My app is running a background service using `AlarmManager`. The service downloads a JSON from server and checks if some value is matching. Right now it is triggered every 10 minutes but I am thinking of increasing the interval to 5 minutes to have more accuracy.

Ideally the service should run every few minutes but I don't want to drain the user's battery too much. What is a reasonable and healthy (battery-wise) schedule interval?

Comment: Why not allow the user to configure the interval? What you think is "reasonable and healthy" may not match what the user thinks is "reasonable and healthy". Bear in mind that in Doze mode, your code will not be able to access the Internet nearly that frequently, unless you convince the user to add your app to the battery optimization whitelist, so you may need a different plan for Android 6.0+ devices anyway.

Comment: we cannot decide for you how often you need to check that value

Comment: You should consider using a Job Scheduler.

Comment: You are right, users should decide how often they want the value updated. I am complicating too much with out-of-the-box automatization. @eCDroid, why is `Job Scheduler` better than AlarmManager? Does it bypass the Doze mode?

Comment: If you have to poll a server, instead of using AlarmManager you could also look into JobScheduler or Firebase Job Dispatcher to do this type of scheduling.  Both of those options allow you to schedule recurring work at certain intervals, but you can also specify criteria that would only run the work when an internet connection is available.  Those two options can also defer work when the device is not being actively used.  If your app data only needs to be updated when the user is active on the device, you can save a lot of battery life using this approach.

Comment: the distinction should be clear. Alarmmanager is for managing alarms. Jobscheduler is for scheduling jobs. Many people use alarmmanager for scheduling tasks/jobs, but it's not meant for that

Comment: @ScottKronheim I need to poll the server even when user is not using the device (I am detecting price change and users want to be notified even when away from phone).

Comment: @CommonsWare for Android 6.0+ I am using [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle). This should be enough, right?

Comment: OK, then you need AlarmManager to reliably wake up the device and you should allow the user to configure how often it should wake up.

Comment: `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` will get you control, but IIRC that will not grant you Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that it is best to transfer this decision to user. With Android 6.0+, developers should also be aware of Doze mode which will prevent AlarmManager from trigerring.

Check comments for detailed discussion.